# ArchUnit: how to check for access to Bean-creation methods?

Tags: archunit

Spring supports the creation of Beans using methods. E.g. a definition like so:

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource springBatchDataSource() {
        SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        ... rest of init code omitted for brevity ...
        return dataSource;
    }
```

defines a Bean "SpringBatchDataSource". That Bean can then be used for Autowiring etc.

However, we had a couple of cases where junior colleagues hadn't understood that concept and had instead called the method to create an object of that type, i.e. instead of

```
...
@Autowire
DataSource ds;
...
```

they had written something like:

```
...
DataSource ds = springBatchDataSource();
...
```

If you do that at several places you end up having multiple objects instead of all talking to the same, single Bean (as was intended - that Bean should be (considered) a singleton in your application). The multiple objects then caused major issues in our application.

I thus now want to add an ArchUnit-check to prevent the access to methods that are actually Bean creators. How do I do that?

I found a `callMethodWhere(...)`-method that takes a predicate on methods and I found a predicate `areAnnotatedWith(<class>.class)`, so that would become: `areAnnotatedWith(Bean.class)`. But I am lost in how to combine and apply these, i.e. what would need to replace the `???` in my below snippet?

```
    @ArchTest
    void checkNoCallToBeanCreators(JavaClasses classes) {

        ArchRule rule = noClasses()
            .should().callMethodWhere(???.areAnnotatedWith(Bean.class));

        rule.check(classes);
    }
```

Or is there some better, more elegant or even straight forward way of checking this?

Answer (score 0):

> I found a `callMethodWhere(...)`-method that takes a predicate on methods

You're wrong in a relevant detail: [`callMethodWhere(...)`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/1.0.0-rc1/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/syntax/elements/ClassesShould.html#callMethodWhere(com.tngtech.archunit.base.DescribedPredicate)) takes a predicate for *[`JavaMethodCall`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/1.0.0-rc1/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaMethodCall.html)s,* not for *[`JavaMethod`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/1.0.0-rc1/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaMethod.html)s.*
The actually called method is the [`target`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/1.0.0-rc1/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaAccess.html#getTarget()) of a method call.

With [`JavaAccess.Functions.Get.target`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/1.0.0-rc1/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaAccess.Functions.Get.html#target()),  you can conveniently transform a predicate for `JavaMethod`s to a predicate for `JavaMethodCall`s. With

```java
import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaAccess.Functions.Get.target;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.properties.CanBeAnnotated.Predicates.annotatedWith;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition.noClasses;
```

you can write your rule as

```java
noClasses().should().callMethodWhere(target().is(annotatedWith(Bean.class)))
```